# Logrotate: Run postrotate script with rotated file

Tags: linux, logrotate

I'm rotating log files with `logrotate` with `copytruncate`, and I need to run a script with the new filename as argument. I understand I can use `$1` within `postrotate`, but that gives me the name of the rotated file - not the one with the date extension.

So basically I have:

`/var/log/myapp/server.log`

When I run this logrotate config:

```
/var/log/myapp/server.log {
  copytruncate
  rotate 1008
  dateext
  dateformat -%s
  create 660 syslog syslog
  postrotate
    python3 /opt/myapp/test.py $1 > /dev/null
  endscript
}
```

I get

```
/var/log/myapp/server.log <-- (now empty)
/var/log/myapp/server.log-1536844088
```

Can I run a script on `/var/log/myapp/server.log-1536844088` in postrotate somehow?

Comment: without testing, it seems like you'd have to use the `dateformat` knowledge and have the script glob for "$1"${dateformat}

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm curious what you tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding that logrotate will pass the name of the log file to the script in `postrotate`; you could use the script and the first parameter and the knowledge that logrotate has created rotated files using the `-%s` dateformat to generate a list of those files:

```
import sys
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1])):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]) + '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'):
                print(file)
```

This is my first python script, so it may not be idiomatic, but hopefully shows the idea. The fnmatch() function uses a glob that should cover you for several years (until late November of 2286), when 9,999,999,999 seconds will roll over to 10,000,000,000. You could "widen" the glob so that it "just" requires "10 digits and then anything":

```
...
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]) + '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'):
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I came up with that but was hoping there is a more elegant solution within logrotate itself. But this will work. Thanks!

Comment: According to the docs, logrotate passes the base log name (given before the curly braces, possibly a wildcarded list), not the rotated names, so you have to come up with them yourself. A fun experiment may be to pass a wildcard on the python3 postrotate line.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a suffix to your  `dateformat -%s`, like `X`, then you should be able to find a unique file `*X` and after renaming it without the X, hand it to your python:

```
dateformat -%sX
postrotate
  for f in *X; do mv "$f" "${f%X}" && test.py "${f%X}"; done
endscript
```

I used a `for` loop to make it a bit less fragile. You may need to check this passes through your `/bin/sh` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
postrotate
  python3 /opt/myapp/test.py $1-`date '+%Y%m%d'` > /dev/null
endscript
```

This will work as long as it's run the same day.

Answer (score 0):

from `man logrotate`:

> Normally, the absolute path to the log file is passed as the first argument to the script and the absolute path to the final rotated log file is passed as the second argument to the script.

I think you just need to check the second argument.